# findContours: OpenCV has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, opencv, breakpoints, contour

I'm trying to use findContours in OpenCV. When I debug my program, everything works fine until

```
findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

I get the message:

> OpenCVFirst.exe has triggered a breakpoint

I already read that this could be because of linking the wrong OpenCV files, but I linked the right ones with d (for debug) at the end.

My code is like in the official OpenCV example:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

I'm using OpenCV 3.0 in Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 10.

Comment: Did you also recompiled OpenCV with VS 2015 compiler?

Comment: Since you're using VS2015 (MSVC14), I assume you compiled the libraries yourself. Is the input image for findContours image in correct format (CV_8UC1)?

Comment: canny_output.type() returns 0, so I assume it's CV_8UC1 right?
How did you mean recompile it? I extract the files and just included them; nothing with CMake

Comment: Yes, canny output is ok. You need to rebuild OpenCV with MSVC14. Until now your code worked _by accident_.

Comment: Are you sure that it worked by accident? Other OpenCV commands worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still doesn't work. Here is what I did:

1. Download [CMake](https://cmake.org/) and just follow the install wizard.
2. Download the newest release of [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) (this may take some time, depending on your internet connection).
3. Launch CMake GUI and set the source / release dir.
4. I didn't adapt the default settings:
   [image: Step2]
5. Waiting until 'Configuring done' is written in the output line. Then, I clicked 'Generate' and waited for the makefile to be generated.
6. It said 'generating done'.
7. I went to the release folder and opened 'OpenCV.sln' with Visual Studio (I used Visual Studio 2015)
8. Now it loaded some files. When it told me on the left bottom 'ready', I clicked on Build -> Build solution (Strg + Shift + B)
9. Then I included to my existing OpenCV Project the new libs from my new release folder. I still get the same error.